# How can I find $K$?

Tags: calculus

Let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \dfrac{\int_{\sin(x)}^{0.5}e^{\arcsin(t)}dt}{x - \frac{\pi}{6}} & \text{if $x\in D(f),\: x \neq \frac{\pi}{6}$},\\
    K & \text{if $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$}.\end{cases}$$

How can I find $K$? 
I know the function is continuous at $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Am I supposed to take the limit as $x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{6}$ of $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes: continuity guarantees that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi/6} f(x)=f(\pi/6)=K$

Comment: L'Hospital will let you get rid of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since $f$ is continuous at $\pi/6$, we have that $K=f(\pi/6)$ should be equal to the limit
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/6}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \pi/6}\frac{\int_{\sin(x)}^{1/2}e^{\arcsin(t)}dt}{x - \frac{\pi}{6}}.$$
Try to evaluate it by using L'Hopital (why can we apply it?) and the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements). What is the final result?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to evaluate the limit of given function as $x\to\pi/6$. Evaluation of the limit is greatly simplified by the use of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Let $z=\sin x$ and then the numerator is equal to $\int_{z} ^{1/2}e^{\arcsin t} \, dt$ and by FTC we have $$\frac{1}{z-(1/2)}\int_{z}^{1/2}e^{\arcsin t} \, dt\to - e^{\arcsin (1/2)}$$ as $z\to 1/2$. The desired limit is thus $$-e^{\pi/6}\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{\sin x-\sin(\pi/6)}{x-\pi/6}=-e^{\pi/6}\cos(\pi/6)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By the mean value theorem,

$$\frac1{0.5-\sin x}\int_{\sin x}^{0.5}e^{\arcsin t}dt=e^{\arcsin t}$$ for some $t$ in $(0.5,\sin x)$ and your limit is the same as that of

$$\frac{\dfrac12-\sin x}{x-\dfrac\pi6}e^{\pi/6}.$$

Now with a translation of the variable,

$$\frac{\dfrac12-\sin\left(z+\dfrac\pi6\right)}{z}=\frac{\dfrac12-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\sin z-\dfrac12\cos z}{z}=\frac{\sin^2\dfrac z2-\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\sin z}{z}.$$

The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Fixed a minor typo and +1